# Simple change tracker for POCOs

Tags: c#, .net

**Problem**

I have a list of POCO model objects (approximatly 1.000 to 10.000) and I want to track changes on them:

- Check if at least one of the items has changed (to show the user that something changed)
- Get all new, deleted and modified objects to update the state in the database

For the first version, it is enough to support POCOs with primitive property types. However, probably I'll extend it in future to support complex property types.

**Solution**

```
public class ChangeTracker<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private static readonly PropertyInfo[] thePropertyInfos;

    private readonly List<TEntity> myEntities = new List<TEntity>();
    private readonly List<TEntity> myDeletedEntites = new List<TEntity>();
    private readonly HashSet<TEntity> myNewEntities = new HashSet<TEntity>();
    private readonly Dictionary<TEntity, object[]> myStates = new Dictionary<TEntity, object[]>();

    static ChangeTracker()
    {
        thePropertyInfos = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties().ToArray();
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (myStates.ContainsKey(entity))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("It is not possible to add an entity twice.");

        myStates.Add(entity, new object[thePropertyInfos.Length]);
        myNewEntities.Add(entity);
        myEntities.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        myEntities.Remove(entity);
        if (!myNewEntities.Remove(entity))
            myDeletedEntites.Add(entity);
    }

    public void AcceptChanges()
    {
        myNewEntities.Clear();
        myDeletedEntites.Clear();
        foreach (var entity in myEntities)
            myStates[entity] = GetState(entity);
    }

    public bool HasChanges()
    {
        return GetEntities(EntityStates.Deleted 
            | EntityStates.Modified 
            | EntityStates.New)
            .Any();
    }

    private static object[] GetState(TEntity entity)
    { 
        return thePropertyInfos
            .Select(pi => pi.GetValue(entity))
            .ToArray();
    }

    private static void SetState(TEntity entity, object[] state)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < state.Length; i++)
            thePropertyInfos[i].SetValue(entity, state[i]);
    }

    private bool HasChanges(TEntity entity)
    {
        var currentState = GetState(entity);
        var previousState = myStates[entity];

        for (int i = 0; i < currentState.Length; i++)
        {
            if (currentState[i] == null &&
                previousState[i] == null)
                continue;

            if (currentState[i] == null ||
                !currentState[i].Equals(previousState[i]))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetEntities(EntityStates states)
    {
        if (states.HasFlag(EntityStates.New))
            foreach (var entity in myNewEntities)
                yield return entity;

        if (states.HasFlag(EntityStates.Deleted))
            foreach (var entity in myDeletedEntites)
                yield return entity;

        if (!states.HasFlag(EntityStates.Modified) &&
            !states.HasFlag(EntityStates.Unmodified))
            yield break;

        foreach (var entity in myEntities.Where(e => !myNewEntities.Contains(e)))
        {
            var isModified = HasChanges(entity);
            if (states.HasFlag(EntityStates.Modified) && isModified)
                yield return entity;
            else if (states.HasFlag(EntityStates.Unmodified) && !isModified)
                yield return entity;
        }
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum EntityStates
{
    New = 1,
    Deleted = 2,
    Modified = 4,
    Unmodified = 8,
    All = ~0,
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public class TestItem
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}

var changeTracker = new ChangeTracker<TestItem>();
var item1 = new TestItem();
var item2 = new TestItem();
var item3 = new TestItem();
var item4 = new TestItem();
var item5 = new TestItem();

changeTracker.Add(item1);
changeTracker.Add(item2);
changeTracker.Add(item3);
changeTracker.AcceptChanges();
changeTracker.Add(item4);
changeTracker.Add(item5);
item2.Property = "test";
changeTracker.Delete(item3);
changeTracker.Delete(item5);

Assert.IsTrue(changeTracker.HasChanges());
Assert.AreEqual(4, changeTracker.GetEntities(EntityStates.All).Count());
Assert.AreEqual(item1, changeTracker.GetEntities(EntityStates.Unmodified).Single());
Assert.AreEqual(item2, changeTracker.GetEntities(EntityStates.Modified).Single());
Assert.AreEqual(item3, changeTracker.GetEntities(EntityStates.Deleted).Single());
Assert.AreEqual(item4, changeTracker.GetEntities(EntityStates.New).Single());
```

Any feedback is welcome. However, I am specially intrested in alternative more performant solutions (without the overhead of boxing/unboxing and reflection).

**[Edit]**

I also tried binary serialization as "state storing strategy", but it is much slower (~100-200%) and it has the downside that the entity classes have to be marked as serializable.

Comment: `thePropertyInfos` - a new prefix? ;-D

Comment: no, it's the old one for static fields. The prefix for instance fields is still 'my' ;)

Comment: One more question, this time a technical one... why is `EntityStates` a `Flags` enum? It doesn't make much sense that an entity can have more then one state at the same time.

Comment: Becuase it allows to get e.g. all modified, new and deleted entites by combining the enum values: `changeTracker.GetEntities(EntityStates.Modified | EntityStates.New | EntityStates.Deleted)`

Comment: Further more, the enum is not used to associate the entity with a state - just to get entites for special states.

Comment: Oh, I see, but this is a very dirty trick just of a little more convenience in a query.

Comment: I thought it is an appropriated usage for flagged enums. How would you design the "Query API"?

Comment: I'm wondering why don't you just use EF for that? It's pretty good in change tracking.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately the entities are loaded from a REST service, not directly from a database.

Comment: Who cares? :-] You could use ef-core just for change tracking. You don't need a database - in-memory provide would do too https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/ although I guess you don't need any provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## State arrays

These confuse me rather. I'm going to suggest you don't add an 'empty' array in `Add`, and instead add `null`.

```
myStates.Add(entity, null);
```

The empty array *is* a valid state, and as far as I can tell you want this to be treated as a non-set value; `null` is not, and will cause a violent crash if you try to treat it as such (which is good).

This sort of requires a change to `HasChanges` (though I don't think it can be called before on a new entity prior to `AcceptChanges`), to explicitly check if the `previousState` is `null` (which could have some performance benefits, but who cares). Of course, you could use some other explicit sentinel type (i.e. do it properly), or just not add anything to the `myStates` dictionary until such a state exists (has all the benefit of `null` without any of the fear).

## `GetEntities`

`GetEntities` is a bit painful to read. I would be inclined to keep new entities in `myNewEntities` *until* they are accepted (much cheaper in the case where the changes are rejected), just as deleted entities to not appear in `MyEntities`. This will simplify the implementation of `GetEntities`, removing the check for new entities.

You also aren't clearing states stored for deleted entities (should be done in `AcceptChanges`).

## Misc

- Not a big issue, but I would consider making `thePropertyInfos` an `IReadOnlyList<TEntity>` (though I probably wouldn't effect this, since hopefully no-one will ever look at this code).
- This could do with some inline (`\\\`) documentation for the external API, and some indication that it is not thread safe.
- Is there any particular reason why `myEntities` is a `List` and not a `HashSet`? I'd be somewhat inclined to ditch the list completely and just keep the State dictionary (no redundancy -> less effort to maintain)
- No `RejectChanges`? Without this, certain bits can be simplified considerably (e.g. ditch state as soon as you delete something).

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback, your points are valid and I have changed the implementation as suggested in 'state arrays' and 'GetEntities'. The problem with RejectChange is, that the application holds it's own list of entities. If entites were deleted, reject changes would not restore the entites in the application's list but revert changes of the non-deleted entites. Therefore I decide to not support RejectChanges .